# How do I prove this positive definiteness?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A \in \mathbb{C}^{nxn}$ is positive definite iff $T=\frac{(A+A^H)}{2}$ is positive definite where $H$ denotes the conjugate transpose.

I can think of using inner products.
Let $A$ be positive definite.
$T$ is positive definite
$\iff \langle Tv,v \rangle > 0$ for non-zero $v$
$\iff \frac{1}{2} ( \langle Av,v \rangle + \langle A^Hv,v \rangle ) > 0 $ which is true iff $A^H$ is also positive definite. How do I prove that, as well as the other part i.e. $A$ is positive definite whenever $T$ is?

Link: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html

Comment: where did this come from?  This claim is **false** since the quadratic form of the skew hermitian part of A isn't necessarily identically zero (something that is true however when the scalar field is $\mathbb R$).

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html

Comment: you should put that link in your original post--you and Wolfram are using a non-standard definition of positive definite.  The standard definition of positive definition is $\mathbf x^*A\mathbf x \gt 0$ for any $\mathbb x\in \mathbb C^n-\{\mathbf 0\}$.  To prove your claim write $A=\frac{1}{2}\big(A+A^H\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(A-A^H\big)$ where the first term is hermitian and the second is skew hermitian.  Then show Hermitian quadratic forms are always real valued and skew hermitian are always purely imaginary.  The definition you use 'forgets' the imaginary component and the result follows.

Comment: Okay. So how do I prove that the claim is false for the standard definition?

Answer (score 1):

A being positive definite means, for all $\mathbf{x}$:

$$\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x} > 0$$

Keep in mind that $\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}$ is just a real number so it is equal to its hermitian conjugate.

So:

$$\mathbf{x}^T (T) \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}^T \frac{(A + A^H)}{2} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}^T \frac{A}{2} \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^T \frac{A^H}{2} \mathbf{x}$$

The two terms $\mathbf{x}^T \frac{A}{2} \mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}^T \frac{A^H}{2} \mathbf{x}$ are equal because they are just real numbers so they do not change when applying the hermitian conjugation. So iff one is positive so is the other one.

Comment: I don’t understand why $x^HAx$ will always be real.

Comment: @user733666 good question. I am not really a mathematician so I cannot prove this to you but think that  $x^H x$ is the length of the vector, so it must be real. Generalizing $x^H A x$ is something like the length of the vector if the space is deformed by A. This length might even be negative!! (special relativity) but it would really feel weird to have an imaginary length. Explicit computation should prove this for dimension 2 and 3. Maybe higher dimension it is possible to use induction?

Comment: $x^H A x$ > 0 implies that $x^H A^H x = (x^H A x)^H =x^H A x > 0$ so $A^H$ is also positive definite. Does that make sense?

Comment: transposition does not change eigenvalues, so reasonably hermitian conjugation does not change real eigenvalues, so matrixes remain positive definite when undergoing it. It feels reasonable.